# How to make login form with admin and user in php

Tags: php, html, mysql

i want to make log-in form with admin and user, but i can't use the session_start() because it always make my variable undefined and it doesn't show any result. is there anybody who can help me? thanks in advance here is my code:

```
    <html>
    <body>

    <?php
    mysql_connect( "localhost" , "admin" , "123") or die(mysql_error());
    mysql_select_db("minimart_database") or die(mysql_error());
    ?>

    <form id="home_id" method ="POST" enctype ="multipart/form-data">
    <script>
    function submitForm(action)
    {
    document.getElementById('home_id').action=action;
    document.getElementById('home_id').submit();
    }
    </script>

    <p align = right> Username: <input type ="text" name ="user" placeholder="Enter username">
    <p align = right> Password: <input type ="password" name ="pass" placeholder="Enter password">
    <input type="submit" value="login"  name="submit" 

     <?php
    mysql_connect( "localhost" , "admin" , "123") or die(mysql_error());
    mysql_select_db("minimart_database") or die(mysql_error());
    ?>

    <?php 

    $user=$_POST['user'];
    $pass=$_POST['pass'];
    $user=stripslashes('$user');
    $pass=stripslashes('$pass');
    $user=mysql_real_escape_string('$user');
    $pass=mysql_real_escape_string('$pass');

    $query="SELECT * FROM account WHERE username='$user' AND password='$pass'";
    $result=mysql_query($query);
    $count=mysql_num_rows($result);
        $row=mysql_fetch_array($result);
    if (isset($_POST['submit']))

    if ($count==1){
    session_start();
    $session("user");
    $session("pass") ;


            if ($row['usertype']==0){
            header("location:admin_home.php");
            echo ("you logged in as admin");
    }
            elseif ($row['usertype']==1) {
            header("location:cashier_home.php");
            echo ("you logged in as cashier");
    }


    else {
    echo "invalid password and username";


    }
    }

    ?>
    </body>
    </html>
```

here is my updated code and the complete code for the whole form :

```
<html>
<body>

<?php
mysql_connect( "localhost" , "admin" , "123") or die(mysql_error());
mysql_select_db("minimart_database") or die(mysql_error());
?>

<form id="home_id" method ="POST" enctype ="multipart/form-data">
<script>
function submitForm(action)
{
document.getElementById('home_id').action=action;
document.getElementById('home_id').submit();
}
</script>

<p align = right> Username: <input type ="text" name ="user" placeholder="Enter username">
<p align = right> Password: <input type ="password" name ="pass" placeholder="Enter password">
<input type="submit" value="login"  name="submit" >


<?php 


if (isset($_POST['submit'])){
    $user=$_POST['user'];
$pass=$_POST['pass'];
$user=stripslashes('$user');
$pass=stripslashes('$pass');
$user=mysql_real_escape_string('$user');
$pass=mysql_real_escape_string('$pass');
$query="SELECT * FROM account WHERE username='$user' AND password='$pass'";
$result=mysql_query($query);
$count=mysql_num_rows($result);

if ($count==1){
session_start();
$_SESSION["user"]=$user;
$_SESSION["pass"]=$pass ;
$row=mysql_fetch_array($result);

        if ($row['usertype']==0){
        header("location:admin_home.php");
        echo ("you logged in as admin");
}
        elseif ($row['usertype']==1) {
        header("location:cashier_home.php");
        echo ("you logged in as cashier");
}


else {
echo "invalid password and username";


}
}
}
?>


<p align=left><input type="text" name="search" placeholder="enter barcode or item name"><input type="submit" name="searched" onclick="submitForm('finalhome.php')">

<?php
$output="";
if (isset($_POST['search'])){
$searchq=$_POST['search'];
$searchq=mysql_real_escape_string($searchq);
$order="SELECT * FROM stock WHERE barcode LIKE '%$searchq' OR itemname LIKE '%$searchq'";
$result=mysql_query($order);
$count=mysql_num_rows($result);

if ($count>=1){
        while($row=mysql_fetch_array($result)){
                $barcode=$row['barcode'];
                $itemname=$row['itemname'];
                $description=$row['description'];
                $amount=$row['amount'];
                $stocks=$row['stocks'];
                $location=$row['location'];
        }
            $output="<div>'.$barcode.' '.$itemname.' '.$description.' '.$amount.' '.$stocks.' '.$location.' </div>"; 
            }
            else
            {
            $output='no results';
            }
     }  
?>
<table border=5 align=center >
<tr><th>Barcode  </th><th>Item name </th><th>Description</th><th>Amount</th><th>Stock</th><th>Location</th>
</tr>
<tr><td>$_POST['$barcode']</td><td>$_POST['$itemname']</td><td>S_POST['$description']</td><td>$_POST['$amount']</td><td>$_POST['$stock']</td><td>$_POST['$location</td></tr>

</table>

<?php print("$output"); ?> 

</body>
</html>
```

the problem now, when the user log-in it doesn't go to admin_home.php or to the cashier_home.php. when i click log-in button, it shows the search data.

here is the code for my admin_home.php:

```
<?php
session_start();

if (isset[$_SESSION['user']=$user) || (isset[$_SESSION['pass']=$pass ){
echo "success login"; }


?>
```

Comment: Sidenote: Why are you connecting twice?

Comment: By "always makes my variable undefined" which variable?  Can you see session cookies being set in your browser?

Comment: Plus these will fail `$session("user");
$session("pass");` which should be `$_SESSION["user"]; 
$_SESSION["pass"];` Which is most likely why you're saying your sessions are failing as `undefined`.

Comment: connecting twice is one of my mistake. thank you for the comment. what is the another mistake i have?

Comment: Fred-ii- , i did what you said but this the result Notice: Undefined index: user in D:\xampp\htdocs\finalhome.php on line 30

Notice: Undefined index: pass in D:\xampp\htdocs\finalhome.php on line 31.

Comment: dethtron5000 , i am just a begginner in php so i don't know what is session cookies?

Comment: Probably because of the location for `if (isset($_POST['submit']))` anything outside of that is being ignored once you click the submit button.

Comment: what i'm going to do? the error is the same even i put the other codes inside of if (isset($_POST['submit']))

Comment: @vanesa did you change $session("user"); to $session["user"]; ?

Comment: @kraysak `$session["user"];` ?

Comment: @kraysak i already did that but still it is not working

Comment: do i need to put code in admin_home.php and cashier_home.php just to make it working?

Comment: @Fred-ii-  i mean change the () to [].. another one, this variables should have some data, example $_SESSION["user"]=$user  check http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.session-start.php

Comment: Yes you're right. That's actually what I meant to write in one of my first comments (slight case of dyslexia). `$_SESSION["user"]=$user;` and `$_SESSION["pass"]=$pass;` @kraysak

Comment: $_SESSION["user"]=$user; and $_SESSION["pass"]=$pass; i'm going to put these code in the form of admin_home.php and cashier_home.php?

Comment: @Fred-ii- if ($count==1){
session_start();
$_SESSION["user"]=$user;
$_SESSION["pass"]=$pass; i did what you said on my home_id form

Comment: Is `session_start();` inside all your other `.php` files and are you also checking if both session variables are set and not empyty? @vanesa

Comment: i don't have any idea how to code it . please help me what is the format?

Comment: @Fred-ii- , is this what you meant to say, <?php
session_start();

if (isset[$_SESSION['user']=$user) || (isset[$_SESSION['pass']=$pass ){
echo "success login"; }
?>  i put this on the admin_home.php . but it still not working . it doesn't go to the admin page

Comment: @vanesa that it's totally wrong

Comment: what is the correct code to put in admin_home.php to access it by the admin when he log-in?

Comment: Storing passwords as plain-text is **dangerous**, and using the obsolete `mysql_query` interface is doubly worrying, it has some serious problems. Instead of writing your own user access system, a [development framework](http://codegeekz.com/best-php-frameworks-for-developers/) usually comes with one that works well and is tested for security concerns. It looks like you used the same reference as in [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22339517/would-this-php-login-code-work-in-implemented-on-web-server#comment33952015_22339517), which is woefully out of date.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

the problem seems to be in those lines:

```
$session("user");
$session("pass") ;
```

in [session_start()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.session-start.php) you will see that those lines are wrong, it should be

```
$_SESSION["user"]=$user;
$_SESSION["pass"]=$pass ;
```

please, test this code (it shoul work, i hope ;) )

```
<html>
<body>
<form id="home_id" method="POST" action="<?php echo $_SERVER[PHP_SELF]?>">
<script>
function submitForm(action)
{
document.getElementById('home_id').action=action;
document.getElementById('home_id').submit();
}
</script>

<p align = right> Username: <input type ="text" name ="user" placeholder="Enter username">
<p align = right> Password: <input type ="password" name ="pass" placeholder="Enter password">
<input type="submit" value="login"  name="submit" >

</body>
</html>

<?php
if (isset($_POST['submit'])){

        mysql_connect( "localhost" , "admin" , "123") or die(mysql_error());
        mysql_select_db("minimart_database") or die(mysql_error());

        $user=$_POST['user'];
        $pass=$_POST['pass'];
        $user=stripslashes('$user');
        $pass=stripslashes('$pass');
        $user=mysql_real_escape_string('$user');
        $pass=mysql_real_escape_string('$pass');

        $query="SELECT * FROM account WHERE username='$user' AND password='$pass'";
        $result=mysql_query($query) or die ("error: ".mysql_error());

            if (mysql_num_rows($result)==1){

                session_start();
                $_SESSION["user"]=$user;
                $_SESSION["pass"]=$pass ;

                        $row=mysql_fetch_array($result);
                        if ($row['usertype']==0){
                        header("location:admin_home.php");
                        }
                        elseif ($row['usertype']==1) {
                        header("location:cashier_home.php");
                        }

                       }
                else 
                echo "invalid password and username";

}//from isset(submit)
?>
```

debugg..

```
if (mysql_num_rows($result)==1){
        echo "only 1 record in database";
                session_start();
                $_SESSION["user"]=$user;
                $_SESSION["pass"]=$pass ;

                        $row=mysql_fetch_array($result);
                        if ($row['usertype']==0){
                        echo "admin user";
                        }
                        elseif ($row['usertype']==1) {
                        echo "normal user";
                        }

    }
        else 
                echo "invalid password and username";
```

Comment: i already did that. the problem now it doesn't go to admin_home.php if the user is admin and go to cashier_home.php if the user is normal user ?

Comment: do you get a error or didn't go where supposed to do?

Comment: i didn't get any error,but it doesn't go to the form. i don't know what code i'm going to add to the form admin_home.php and cashier_home.php

Comment: @vanesa, I'm pretty sure you have to give an absolute URL.

Comment: i am just new in php, where to put the URL? what URL i'm going to put?

Comment: @kraysak in my form i still have search box . that's why i use script to have multiple action. what do you this <?php echo $_SERVER[PHP_SELF]?>

Comment: @vanesa is hard for me to explain, i am don't speak english.. but first, could you test the code in my answer?.

Comment: <?php echo $_SERVER[PHP_SELF]?>  basically mean, that your form will send the information to the same page

Comment: i tried your code and when i click log-in button. the error goes like this "Access forbidden!

You don't have permission to access the requested object. It is either read-protected or not readable by the server.

If you think this is a server error, please contact the webmaster.

Error 403

localhost
Apache/2.4.2 (Win32) OpenSSL/1.0.1c PHP/5.4.4"

Comment: It is strange, weel remove the action="<?php echo $_SERVER[PHP_SELF]?>" and test it again

Comment: it doesn't go to the admin_home page or to the cashier_home page also it doesn't give result if it is wrong password or username. as i said earlier, it connect to my my search button and gives result for the search

Comment: mmmm, so we should start to debugg... test the new code that i will post please..

Comment: i made a mistake before, could you please test the code, if that doesnt work, replace the code before if (mysql_num_rows($result)==1){ for the last part of code

Comment: @kraysak i tried it but still have same error. i don't know how to use  URL and i think that is the problem. Do you have any idea how to use URL? do i need to write isset code in my admin_home.php and cashier_home.php   ?

Comment: yo mean the "Access forbidden! .. error? but, what it says in the url?

Comment: and the line "if (isset[$_SESSION['user']=...etc" is wrong.. remove it in all your pages.

Comment: ah. so URL is not the problem. sorry, i think i'm wrong.

Comment: just to test, in admin_home.php, just add 
<?php
 session_start(); echo $_SESSION['user'];
?>

Comment: i tried it but still the same problem that i mentioned earlier

Comment: **+1** for all your hard work. @kraysak You deserve more, but that's all that SO allows per member ;-)